# Regex Issue in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am comparing data type values from expected value which stored in database to actual response.I am using below code for validating value .I am getting undefined "string_between_markers" method error while comparing.I understood there is no predefined method is available in expected_value string.How to call string_between_markers for compare regex.
In DB Pattern regex has below value Pattern_Regex_[^([0-9]{1,3}).([0-9]{1,3}).([0-9]{1,3}).([0-9]{1,3})]

```
     def validate_value? (actual_value)
     if expected_value.include? "Pattern_Regex"
      #   get the regex from []
      regex = expected_value.string_between_markers("[","]")

      if expected_value.match(regex)
        result = "Passed"
       end
      end

        #String Between Method
        def string_between_markers marker1, marker2
     self[/#{Regexp.escape(marker1)}(.*?)#{Regexp.escape(marker2)}/m, 1]
      end
         end
```

Comment: Can you please check if your code is correctly formatted? It looks like you have `string_between_markers` defined inside of `valudate_value?`

Comment: ok done.Typo error.

Comment: The issue is still there. You have to close each `def` and `if`. Please add `end` before `#String Between Method` and check if it works.

Comment: yes.It is big code that i have copied few parts.Thats is the reason i have missed end.Still i am getting undefined method error

Comment: How to call custom string method in rails? i think it is searching for pre defined method for expected_value string then it is showing string_between_markers method is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are calling a method on `String` that is not defined correctly. There are two ways.

**First solution**

```
def string_between_markers(input, marker1, marker2)
  input[/#{Regexp.escape(marker1)}(.*)#{Regexp.escape(marker2)}/m, 1]
end
```

and then call it like this:

```
string_between_markers(expected_value, "[","]")
```

**Second solution**

Create a file like `lib/ext/string.rb` with the following code:

```
class String
  def string_between_markers(marker1, marker2)
    self[/#{Regexp.escape(marker1)}(.*)#{Regexp.escape(marker2)}/m, 1]
  end
end
```

Then, in your code, you have to require this file by calling `require 'ext/string'` or by adding `lib` folder to autoload paths.

After that, you are calling the method as you did before:

```
expected_value.string_between_markers("[","]")
```

Comment: Thanks.Now it entering string_between_markers(Second solution helps).Now I am getting  premature end of char-class: /^([0-9/  error.

Comment: @user1984 please replace `(.*?)` with `(.*)` in the `string_between_markers`. I have already updated my answer

Comment: Thansk.Issue fixed.